# How can I connect molecular gateway with express-nodejs app?

Tags: moleculer

I am learning the microservice architecture and trying to use molecular. It seems like it can control many aspects of my 'express-nodejs' apps. Before, I migrate each nodejs apps to molecular, is it possible to connect molecular gate API and my nodejs app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/moleculer-web.html for web api gate.
And use transport https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/networking.html between nodejs apps.
One nodejs app this is one moleculer broker and many services in every is broker.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the ideology of broker and service. If I compare them with kubernetes and dockers, kubernetes = brokers and dockers = services? Each service can have REST task and broker is the one who manages these services correct?

Comment: Each service can fulfill its role as a separate REST request, for [example](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer-web/blob/master/examples/test.service.js#L27).

Services by themselves are not separate processes.
Services can be divided into groups and each group of services will be headed by one broker. You can do it for one service by a one broker.

Brokers communicate with each other and help services interact with each other, schema [image](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/assets/overview.svg).